# Cannot use pip on windows 10 after installing python

Tags: python, windows

I have tried a number of times to use pip in Windows 10 after installing python 3.11 from python.org.  The path to the \Scripts folder containing pip is already in the environment variables.  Python will execute when using the launcher (when I try it from the command prompt or powershell it opens the windows store).

When I try pip at the command line I get the following:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Similar errors trying pip -v, pip -help, etc.

I have tried different python installation methods, including MS Windows store and direct download from python.org. If it matters, I am trying to install psychopy.  I confirmed that pip and pip3 are in the scripts directory.

Comment: Have you tried adding both directories where Python is installed in the Path environmental variable? Something like:

C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\

C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\'